# How do I keep water from entering via the gas inlet pipe whenever there is heavy rain?

Tags: pipe, gas

There is water dripping from the gas inlet pipe coming inside the house at the basement whenever there is heavy rain.

How do I stop water coming in whenever there is rain? Is there is some sort of sealant that needs to be applied? If so, what type of sealant?

Comment: A picture of where the pipe enters the building would allow us to answer the question more accurately. Otherwise it would just be speculation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/244221/pre-existing-galvanized-gas-pipe-through-foundation-underground-with-no-sleeve/244224#244224

Comment: Does the pipe enter your basement above or below ground level?

Comment: What kind of pipe? What kind of wall? Where relative to grade? Is freezing a possibility? Please revise to add enough detail for us to help.

Answer (score 3):

Caulking.

Preferably butyl if you can find any these days (it does not fully harden, so it's more tolerant of thermal movement between steel/iron pipe and building than silicone or polyurethanes.) But polyurethanes may be the best you can find these days.

Applied on the outside. Use backer rod if there's a large gap.

Comment: Not as flexible as caulking... but what are your thoughts about plumber's putty?

Comment: Wonderfull answer, executive stile, short and to the point

Comment: @spuck, plumber's putty isn't appropriate. It's not sticky enough or (as far as I know) designed for exterior use. _Duct seal_, on the other hand, would be.

Comment: Anything wrong with using duct seal compound, a.k.a. "monkey shit?"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is "anything that won't chemically attack the pipe". My first instinct is hydraulic cement, but a spray foam would probably do the job.

As the other answer says, caulking might be a better answer.

Comment: Spray foam will break down under UV exposure (Source: Personal experience). It will work, but it will need to be refreshed every couple of years. Also, I'm not certain that it's 100% waterproof, especially once the outer skin has degraded.

Comment: If it's leaking, I'm presuming underground entry; no UV. And I have an aboveground hole thru my foundation's south wall where the foam has been slowly degrading and eroding back but has maintained an adequate seal for a decade; should probably be redone soon, admittedly. (Old oil filler penetration, now used to run a compressed air hose out for inflating tires. I can't use an expanding cement with these old bricks; could use lime mortar now that I have some.)